# Restrict characters limit on copy & paste in UITextView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am restricting user to not exceed limit of 200 characters while typing or copy & paste the text. Let's say I have text character count of 190. Now I can type only 10 characters more. Even if I paste 200 charecters it will paste only initial 10 charecters of that copied text.

Now issue is when user selects a few words from UITextView. Here words are still selected as highlighted. Now when I paste copied words on selected words then it allows to paste more charecters even if limit is 200.

**Code:**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) {
    let str = (textView.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

    if str.length >= 200 {
        let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 200)
        textView.text = str.substring(to: index).trim
    }


    let remainChars = 200 - textView.text!.length
    self.descriptionCountLabel.text? = String(remainChars)
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure that if the text view has 190 characters, and the user has selected 20, and then tries to paste 100, that the 20 selected only get replaced with the first 30 pasted characters leaving the text view with 200 characters?

Comment: Max limit is 200 if user has typed 190 chars now user can enter only 10 more chars.Now if user has copied 100 chars & paste then it will only paste first 10 chars.I have handles this sceneario.Now if user select few words & those words are highlighted & user paste those copied words while those selected words are selected (highlighted) then it allow to paste more than 200 words

Comment: If you explicitly set the text view's `text` property in your `shouldChangeTextIn`, you must return `false` at that point. Only return `true` if the change should happen as-is.

Comment: where to return false in my code

Comment: At the end of the `if` block, after you set `textView.text`.

Comment: I hope you understood what was the issue.This issue only occured if i select text & selected text is highlighted & i paste only then i excceds the max limit

Comment: Better to use editingDidChange and crop it using array method prefix(n) in your String characters

Comment: can show me some code.I am not able to understand this way

Answer (score 4):

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if range.length >= 200 && text.isEmpty {
        return false
    }

    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    if newText.count > 200 {
        textView.text = String(newText.prefix(200))
    }
    return newText.count <= 200
}
```

It will prevent the undo crash, but also will not undo if pasted text was greater than your limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this although it will crash with "undo":

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.text = String(textView.text.prefix(200))
}
```

This will protect against the bug but it's not ideal as the user will lose the ability to undo if the limit is exceeded:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.count > 200 { textView.undoManager?.removeAllActions() }
    textView.text = String(textView.text.prefix(200))
}
```